# How to plot multiple learning curve from different model on the same graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, graph

I have few models that I have trained, and wanted to plot the learning curve of each model on a single graph

I tried this, and worked. But it felt redundant.

```
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(model, 
                                                        train_dummies, 
                                                        y,
                                                        cv=5,
                                                      scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Because I need to repeat the **train_scores** and **test_scores** for each **model**.

I tried it using **for** loop.

First , I saved the models in an array.

```
arr = [m1,m2,m3]
```

But when I started the **for** loop, it only produced a single line on the graph.

```
for i in arr:
  train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(i, 
                                                    train_dummies, 
                                                    y,
                                                    cv=5,
                                              scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
  train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
  train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)

  test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
  test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)


  plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, label="Cross-validation score")
```

Here is the desired output

[image: Desired output]

Will someone show me what am I lacking ? Your time is deeply appreciated.

Comment: are you aware that `test_mean` is not defined within the for loop?

Comment: @SamProell thanks for pointing. left it out on purpose. :)

Comment: i can't spot anything wrong with what you are doing.. This works for me: https://gist.github.com/SamProell/59d1d4fac1e319b3d19e98335058fc3f

Comment: @SamProell, thanks. My mistake was, iterating the variable instead of the modelling itself. I saved model_1 earlier, and iterate using model_1. I guess the coding could not pickup what is model_1 and thats why it plotted the graph separately. If you put your gist here, I would gladly star it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't spot anything wrong with what you are doing.. This works for me (taken in part from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target
for i in [GaussianNB(), SVC(gamma=0.001)]:
    (train_sizes,
     train_scores,
     test_scores) = learning_curve(i, X, y, cv=5)
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, label="Cross-validation score")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```